# How to handle PutObject operation: Access Denied for Lamba

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to use a lambda function to write some text to a file in S3.
Below is the function.

I get this error
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

The bucket is
[image]

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket='tessstinggbucccket'
    key='june/22/testlog1.txt'
    
    some_binary_data = b'Here we have some data'

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    object.put(Body=some_binary_data)
```

Comment: Does the AWS Lambda function have an IAM Role assigned? What permissions are being granted by the IAM Role?

Answer (score 0):

You are required to provide write/put permissions to your lambda functions to give them the capability to write on your s3 buckets. You can achieve it using the code below:

```yaml
      # Add this property on your lambda function definition inside the SAM template
      Policies:
        - S3WritePolicy:
            BucketName: "YourBucketNameHere"
```